# Counting table rows where a column value first appears after date XYZ

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have an `orders` table that looks like so:

| orderId | customerId | orderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 320 | 45 | 2020-01-01 |
| 455 | 67 | 2021-02-11 |
| 122 | 45 | 2019-04-22 |

Based on this I need to count all 'new' customers that first entered the system after date XYZ.

I'm thinking of something involving a `having` clause but wondered if there was a better way to go about it.  Something along these lines (SQL may not be exact, but the general idea):

`select count(*) from (select distinct(customerId) from orders group by customerId having min(orders.orderDate) > XYZ) as foo`

Is there a better / faster way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wanted the count of new customers coming into the system after `2021-02-11`, you could try:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customerId)
FROM orders o1
WHERE
    orderDate > '2021-02-11' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o2
                WHERE o2.customerId = o1.customerId AND o2.orderDate <= '2021-02-11');
```

The above logic reads, in plain English, to count any customer record appearing *after* `2021-02-11`, where that customer also did not appear previously in a record on or before `2021-02-11`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is already fine, another option is to use `partition` and count only 1 customerId (alternative of `distinct` keyword)

```
select count(1) from (select 
    row_number() over (partition by customerId order by orderDate asc) rn 
from orders where orderDate > '2020-01-01') t1
where rn = 1
```

Try [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dd3b8c/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are already using this method:

```
select count(*)
from (select customerId, min(orderDate) as first_orderDate
      from orders o
      group by customerId
      having min(orderDate) >= '2021-02-11'
     ) oc;
```

For performance, I would suggest using the `customers` table:

```
select count(*)
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.customerId = c.customerId and
                        o.orderDate < '2021-02-11'
                 );
```

For this, you want an index on `orders(customerId, orderDate)`.